# Laravel Array Searches with Multiselect

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, select, collections

Hello Stackoverflow Community,

I am wondering if you could help with a nagging problem that I've had for the last few days that myself and a friend cannot seem to solve.

I currently have two Models - Newsletters and Tags. Newsletters contains various information, one column in particular is called tags which implodes the values when storing and exploding the selected values on the front end.

The particular section I am working on is the edit functionality.

Currently my edit function shows as follows

```
 public function edit($id, Tag $tag)
{

    $tags = Tag::all();
    $newsletter = Newsletter::find($id);
    $tagged = $newsletter->tags; 
    $selected = explode(",", $tagged);

    // dd($selected);
    return view('newsletter.edit', compact('newsletter', 'tags', 'selected'));
}
```

My front end edit blade file is as follows:

```
 <select name="tags[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" id="tags">         
        @foreach ($tags as $tag)
           <option value="{{ $tag->name}}" {{ (in_array($tag->name, $selected, true)) ? ' selected' : '' }}> {{$tag->name}}</option> 
        @endforeach
     </select>
```

However - it is only passing through one value, and although selected passes the array of values, it does not seem to check against all of them to make all the options selected.

Therefore only one of the 3 options is selected.

I know that I may not be doing it the way most people would with pivot tables, I've been trying to understand some basics and played around in the way I knew how to work it before I got stuck here.

Comment: I don't think you need Tag $tag as a parameter in your function, try @dd($tags, $selected) just before the foreach to see what data you're getting there

Comment: Lets try in_array($tag->name, $selected) instead of in_array($tag->name, $selected, **true**). I think maybe **strict**  parameter causing this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use @if @endif instead of ? : statements.

Try to change your code like this

```
<select name="tags[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" id="tags">         
    @foreach ($tags as $tag)
       <option value="{{ $tag->name}}" @if(in_array($tag->name, $selected, true)) selected @endif }}> {{$tag->name}}</option> 
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks - I managed to solve it shortly after this, it came down to the way the data was storing!